# gsub / sub to extract between certain characters

Tags: r, regex

How can I extract the numbers / ID from the following string in R?

`link <- "D:/temp/sample_data/0000098618-13-000011.htm"`

I want to just extract `0000098618-13-000011`

That is discard the `.htm` and the `D:/temp/sample_data/`.

I have tried grep and gsub without much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) basename** Use `basename` followed by `sub`:

```
sub("\\..*", "", basename(link))
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

**2) file_path_sans_ext**

```
library(tools)
file_path_sans_ext(link)
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

**3) sub**

```
sub(".*/(.*)\\..*", "\\1", link)
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

**4) gsub**

```
gsub(".*/|\\.[^.]*$", "", link)
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

**5) strsplit**

```
sapply(strsplit(link, "[/.]"), function(x) tail(x, 2)[1])
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

**6) read.table**.  If `link` is a vector this will only work if all elements have the same number of /-separated components.  Also this assumes that the only dot is the one separting the extension.

```
DF <- read.table(text = link, sep = "/", comment = ".", as.is = TRUE)
DF[[ncol(DF)]]
## [1] "0000098618-13-000011"
```

Comment: Thanks! what does the `basename` function do?

Comment: Or just `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename("foo/bar/quux.html"))`.

Comment: It Works on the whole data set but `basename` is new to me.

Comment: Look at `?basename`.

Comment: Or a `basename` - `dirname` combo: `dirname(chartr(".", "/", basename(link)))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(link , "[0-9-]+")

# "0000098618-13-000011"
```